# Why is the end of the session also destroying the cookie?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am trying to simulate a Login-Logout (I am a beginner) and I must use both sessions and cookies. 
So I used a cookie that lasts 20seconds and remembers the username and password if I check the 'Remember me' option at the login. 
And also used a session. 
However, when I try to log out, if I do it in the first 20sec, Mozzila is giving me an error.
Why so?

This is the log in file

```html
<?php
session_start();
$user="username";
$pass="password";

//verify if there is a cookie, and if so, log in from the cookie
if(isset($_COOKIE['u']) && isset($_COOKIE['p']) && $_COOKIE['u']==$user && $_COOKIE['p']==$pass){
 header("location: Index.php");
 exit;
 }

if(isset($_POST['sub']))
 if(empty($_POST['name'])) echo "Please write username";
  elseif(empty($_POST['pass'])) echo "Please write password";
  else
   if($_POST['name']==$user && $_POST['pass']==$pass){
  
    if($_POST['rem']=="on"){
     setcookie("u", $_POST['name'],time()+10);
     setcookie("p", $_POST['pass'],time()+10);
     }
     
    $_SESSION['logged']="yes";
    $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
    header("location: Index.php");
    exit;
    }
    else echo "Incorrect data";


?>




<html>
<head>
 <title> Login </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="username" /><br />
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="password"/><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="rem" />Remember me<br />
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Log in" /> 
</form>
</html>
```

This is the Logout:

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION=array();
session_destroy();
header("location: Login.php");
exit;


?>
```

```html
<?php
session_start();

//verificam daca nu a ajuns fortat pe pagina, si ca mai intai s-a logat
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged']) || $_SESSION['logged']!="yes"){
 header("location: Login.php");
 exit; 
 }

?>


<html>
<head>
 <title> Index </title>
</head>
<body>
 Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?>!
 <br /><br /><br />
 <a href="Logout.php"> Log out! </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Comment: please post your session, cookie and logout code

Comment: Do not store passwords in cookies! This is a major security blunder.

Answer (score 0):

**Logout.php:**

Check this logout script. Here i am expiring cookie to stop loop of redirection. Keep all scripts as it is. only update logout.php like this:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION=array();
session_destroy();
setcookie("u", $_POST['name'],time()-10);
setcookie("p", $_POST['pass'],time()-10);
header("location: Login.php");
exit;


?>
```

Comment: Did that. Deleted the cookie in the logout page. But still, if in those 20sec I close mozzila and then reopen the Index, the same error appear. (However, there isn't any error when logging off)

Comment: @LorelaySunshine check my updated answer hope it will solve your issue :)